# ActionBarSherlock Fragments display/access

Tags: android, layout, actionbarsherlock, layout-inflater

I got an Dynamic Layout with a SherlockActionbar.
In Landscape Mode I got two Fragments that should be displayed side by side. But the Second Fragment isn't displayed.

MainActivity onCreate

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH){
            this.setTheme(R.style.Theme_Sherlock);
        }

        if (savedInstanceState != null)
        {
           savedInstanceState.remove ("android:support:fragments");
        } 

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        actionbar = getSupportActionBar(); 

        actionbar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        tab1 = actionbar.newTab().setText("Search"); 
        tab2 = actionbar.newTab().setText("Found"); 
        tab3 = actionbar.newTab().setText("Account");

        Class[] clzs;
        String[] tags;

        if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {

            clzs = new Class[2];
            tags = new String[2];


            clzs[0] = ListSearchFragment.class;
            tags[0] = "listsearch";

            clzs[1] = DetailSearchFragment.class;
            tags[1] = "detailsearch";
        }
        else
        {

            clzs = new Class[1];
            tags = new String[1];
            clzs[0] = ListSearchFragment.class;
            tags[0] = "listsearch";
        }

        tab1.setTabListener(new MainTabListener<SherlockFragment>(this, clzs,tags));


        clzs = new Class[1];
        tags = new String[1];

        clzs[0] = AccountOverviewFragment.class;
        tags[0] = "accountoverview";

        tab2.setTabListener(new MainTabListener<SherlockFragment>(this,  clzs,tags));
        tab3.setTabListener(new MainTabListener<SherlockFragment>(this,  clzs,tags));

        actionbar.addTab(tab1); 
        actionbar.addTab(tab2);
        actionbar.addTab(tab3);
    }
```

MainTabListener:

```
public class MainTabListener <T extends SherlockFragment> implements ActionBar.TabListener{

    public SherlockFragment fragments[];
    private Activity mActivity; 
    private Class<T>[] mClasses;
    private String[] tags;


    public MainTabListener(Activity activity, Class<T>[] clzs, String[] tags) {
        this.mActivity = activity;
        this.mClasses = clzs;
        this.tags = tags;
        this.fragments = new SherlockFragment[mClasses.length];
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        FragmentManager fragMgr = ((FragmentActivity) mActivity).getSupportFragmentManager(); 
        ft = fragMgr.beginTransaction();

        for(int i = 0; i < mClasses.length; i++)
        {
            if (fragments[i] == null) {
                fragments[i] = (SherlockFragment) SherlockFragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClasses[i].getName());
                ft.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragments[i],tags[i]);
            }
            else {
                ft.attach(fragments[i]);
            }           
        }
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
        ft.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        FragmentManager fragMgr = ((FragmentActivity) mActivity).getSupportFragmentManager(); 
        ft = fragMgr.beginTransaction();

        for(int i = 0; i < mClasses.length; i++)
        {
            if (fragments[i] != null) {
                ft.detach(fragments[i]);
            }
        }
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
        ft.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }

}
```

The Layout Gravity and widths are set to 1/3 and 2/3 when the screenorientation is in Landscape Mode.

In Portrait Mode I have one Fragment with a List. When i click on one item, a new Activity is started where the other Fragment is added to a new LinearLayout.

The DetailActivity:

```
public class DetailSearchActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_found_detail);


            FragmentManager fragMgr = this.getSupportFragmentManager(); 
            FragmentTransaction ft = fragMgr.beginTransaction();
            ft.add(R.id.fragment_container,SherlockFragment.instantiate(this, DetailSearchFragment.class.getName()) ,"detailsearch");
            ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);

            ft.commit();

            fragMgr.executePendingTransactions();

            if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
                 finish();
                 return;
            }

            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            try{
            DetailSearchFragment fragmentdetail = (DetailSearchFragment) this.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("detailsearch");

            if (extras != null) {
              String s = extras.getString("title");

              String d = extras.getString("description");

              fragmentdetail.setText(s, d);
            }
            }catch(RuntimeException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}
```

The Problem in Portrait Mode is that the Views in the Fragment doesnt seem to be initialised when i try to set the texts. I get a NullPointerException when trying to get the Textview in the FragmentLayout that is inflated(The default Text is displayed). SO how can i call my setText() method after the FragmentLayout is successfully inflated?

**Edit:**
When I Log my Tags in the TabListener both Fragments (List and Detail) seems to be added to the FragmentTransaction when in LandscapeMode

When i add this to my ListItemClickListener:

```
DetailSearchFragment fragmentdetail = (DetailSearchFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("detailsearch");
Log.d("detailfrag","exists: "+(fragmentdetail != null) + " is in Layout:" + (fragmentdetail.isInLayout()));
```

I get:

```
12-23 13:39:07.440: D/detailfrag(13403): exists: true is in Layout:false
```

**Edit2** Ok I solved the Problem with the two Layouts. You can't add two Fragments to the same container.

TabListener:

```
public class MainTabListener <T extends SherlockFragment> implements ActionBar.TabListener{

    public SherlockFragment fragments[];
    private Activity mActivity; 
    private Class<T>[] mClasses;
    private String[] tags;
    private View[] myViews;
    private int id = 1;

    public MainTabListener(Activity activity, Class<T>[] clzs, String[] tags) {
        this.mActivity = activity;
        this.mClasses = clzs;
        this.tags = tags;
        this.fragments = new SherlockFragment[mClasses.length];
        this.myViews = new View[mClasses.length];
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        FragmentManager fragMgr = ((FragmentActivity) mActivity).getSupportFragmentManager(); 
        ft = fragMgr.beginTransaction();

        for(int i = 0; i < mClasses.length; i++)
        {
            if (fragments[i] == null) {
                fragments[i] = (SherlockFragment) SherlockFragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClasses[i].getName());
                View myView = (View)new LinearLayout(mActivity);
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams llp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                myView.setLayoutParams(llp);
                ViewGroup container = (ViewGroup)mActivity.findViewById(R.id.fragment_container);
                container.addView(myView);
                myView.setId(findId());
                myViews[i] = myView;
                ft.add(myView.getId(), fragments[i],tags[i]);
            }
            else {
                myViews[i].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }           
        }
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
        ft.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

        for(int i = 0; i < mClasses.length; i++)
        {
            if (fragments[i] != null) {
                myViews[i].setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }

    public int findId(){  
        View v = (ViewGroup)mActivity.findViewById(id);  
        while (v != null){  
            v = (ViewGroup)mActivity.findViewById(++id);  
        }  
        return id++;  
    }

}
```

Still got the issue that the setText() method is called before the FragmentView is created when there is just one Fragment in Portrait Mode.

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your code where you add the second fragment if the activity is in a landscape orientation.

Comment: in my onCreate i add 2 Fragments to the TabListener if the Device is in Landscape Mode and the FragmentTransaction.add() id called two times ones for the ListSearch and ones for the DetailSearch but the DetailSearch isnt displayed